# Add Numbers from Each Line Break in Textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have the following in a textarea:

> link|10000
>   link|25000
>   link|58932

I need to remove the characters before the "|" on each line and get the sum of the all the numbers

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So where are you stuck? We don't know specifically where you need help. What did you try that failed to produce the desired result?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Javascript/Jquery so I need help. I know what I am trying to achieve as described my post. I'm not sure how to write the code...

Comment: Also why the downvote and edit on my original post? This is a legitimate question that others might find useful for their projects.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because the question shows no effort to solve the problem. Personal research is the first step. The down vote is legitimate.

Comment: This is a place/community to learn and share script language. If one does not know the proper language, how does one make an attempt to solve something they do not know? This is not a legitimate down vote but an abuse of the system and something that will discourage others from using this site as they will feel it is not a safe place to ask for help without being chastised. Down vote for you. And Thank you to everyone who helped!

Comment: If one does not know the proper language, one does what all other budding developers do, which is to take the initial steps to learn the language. Who are you to lecture on how the site works? Hover your pointer over the down arrow and the first reason it gives is not showing research effort.

Comment: *"Down vote for you."* How so? Are you voting with multiple accounts?

Comment: "Down vote for you."

Its not a down vote for you that will be reflected on this website. However, it is a down vote for you to refuse to help but argue. The down vote I gave you is one for my personal book and there is no reason for you to continue your banter as I am done with your attitude. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short solution:

```
// Gets textarea content
var myTextareaText = document.getElementById('my-textarea-id').value;

// Uses array functions to simplify the process
let sum = myTextareaText.split('\n').map(x=>x.split('|')[1] * 1).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);

// Logs de result
console.log(sum);
```

What was done:

1) Break by line breaks : myTextareaText.split('\n')
2) Foreach line, break by "|", gets the second item and convert it to number: map(x=>x.split('|')[1] * 1)
3) Sum each element: reduce((a,b)=>a+b)

Comment: Excellent! Short but perfect solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```js
  function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value.split("link|").map(Number).reduce(function(a, b){return  a+b; });
}
```

```html
Calculate:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
link|10000
link|25000
link|58932</textarea>

<p>Click the button to calculate.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate it</button>
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Get all numbers from the value using [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method and calculate the sum using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('text');

// get the text area value 
var res = ele.value
  // get all digits combinations , if you want decimal number then use /\d+(\.\d+)?/g
  .match(/\d+/g)
  // iterate and calculate the sum
  .reduce(function(sum, v) {
    // parse the number and add it with previous value
    return sum + Number(v);
    // set initial value as 0
  }, 0);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<textarea id="text">link|10000 link|25000 link|58932
</textarea>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!